# How to find the sum of each columns of a data table with columns are specific dates in a month?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to find the sum of each columns of data table while the column headers are  all in dates of a month. The problem is with the name of column which is in date format.

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Sl no | Name   | 15-Jan-18 | 19-Jan-18 | 21-Jan-18 |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1    |AppyBiju|    7      |           |    2      |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|  2    |Sasi    |    4      |     9     |           |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  3    |Soman   |    8      |     6     |           |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  4    |Pakkaran|    2      |           |    2      |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  5    |Koran   |    5      |           |    1      |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+    
|       |Total   |    22     |     10    |    14     |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

This is my code (`dt` is datatable that contains the data shown above):

```
dt.Rows.Add(i); //  i  = (count of  rows+1 ) for adding new row "total"
dt.Rows[i][1]="Total";
object newt;
foreach(DataColumn c in dt.Columns.Cast<Datacolumn>().Skip(2))
{
    newt=dt.Compute("Sum(+c+)","");
    dt.Rows[i][c]=newt;
}
```

And I also I tried another code like:

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dt.Columns.Cast<Datacolumn>().Skip(2))
{
    for(int j=0; j<dt.Rows.Count-1; j++)
    {
        if(!(dt.Rows[j][c] is DBnull.Value))
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j][c]);
    }
    dt.Rows[i][c]=sum;
}
```

Comment: The variable j should start at one instead of zero.

Comment: That won't works @jdweng

Comment: Are the headers the columns names or are they in the first row of the table?  It is possible the cells are Dates and formatted so you are only seeing the months.  Then you need to use c.Month instead of summing just c.

Comment: @jdweng The dates are column headers. The table describes the amount that each person donates on particular dates in month. And the last row Total  outputs the sum of amount of each day. Can you please explain the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("S1 no", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("15-Jan-18", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("19-Jan-18", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("21-Jan-18", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "AppyBiju", 7, null, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Sasi", 4, 9, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Soman", 8, 6, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Pakkaran", 2, null, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Koran", 5, null, 1 });

            DataRow totalRow =  dt.Rows.Add();
            totalRow[1] = "Total";

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(2))
            {

                //method 2
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[j][c] != DBNull.Value)
                        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j][c]);
                }
                totalRow[c] = sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dates cannot be initialized bcoz, i'm trying to fill it from a database.

Comment: I know.  You can use a DataAdapter to query database and put results into a datatable.  Then use my code to sum column.